# Are there any limitations to # of columns in a SnappyData column table?

Tags: snappydata, nosql

As an example, Cassandra has a 2 billion column limit for a "row key".  Some high volume IoT apps could push that boundary and you should therefore, design accordingly, if using Cassandra.

Is there any size limitations similar to that with SnappyData's column table that I should "design" around as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such design limit with Snappy column tables.

Answer (score 1):

There is such limit:

> we are not going to support anything more than a thousand columns for any of the table types for coming releases

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/issues/769#issuecomment-321240734